# batch put_item with DynamoDB in PHP

Tags: php, nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running into issues sending data to my DynamoDB. I have no idea what the issue is because it appears the program runs correctly, however I don't seem to have any data in my DB. I was able to create tables using [Amazons tutorial](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedCreateTables.html), but when I follow this tutorial, I get a failed response if I try and put **ALL** the items, and a false success when it's only one item, as nothing is updated in the db.

Here's the code, I'm curious specifically if anyone knows a means to debug these kinds of issues.

```
<?php
// If necessary, reference the sdk.class.php file. 
// For example, the following line assumes the sdk.class.php file is 
// in an sdk sub-directory relative to this file
require_once('includes/backend.php'); 

// Instantiate the class
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();

####################################################################
# Setup some local variables for dates

$one_day_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-1 days"));
$seven_days_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-7 days"));
$fourteen_days_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-14 days"));
$twenty_one_days_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-21 days"));

####################################################################
# Adding data to the table

echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo "# Adding data to the table..." . PHP_EOL;

// Set up batch requests
$queue = new CFBatchRequest();
$queue->use_credentials($dynamodb->credentials);

// Add items to the batch
$dynamodb->batch($queue)->put_item(array(
    'TableName' => 'ProductCatalog',
    'Item' => array(
        'Id'              => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER           => '101'              ), // Hash Key
        'Title'           => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING           => 'Book 101 Title'   ),
        'ISBN'            => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING           => '111-1111111111'   ),
        'Authors'         => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_ARRAY_OF_STRINGS => array('Author1')   ),
        'Price'           => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER           => '2'                ),
        'Dimensions'      => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING           => '8.5 x 11.0 x 0.5' ),
        'PageCount'       => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER           => '500'              ),
        'InPublication'   => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_NUMBER           => '1'                ),
        'ProductCategory' => array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING           => 'Book'             )
    )
));


echo "Item put in <b>Reply</b>" . "<br/>";   

// Execute the batch of requests in parallel
$responses = $dynamodb->batch($queue)->send();

// Check for success...
if ($responses->areOK())
{
    echo "The data has been added to the table." . PHP_EOL;
}
    else
{
    utdump($responses);
}
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your region explicitly, e.g. for EU you need to call:

```
$myDynamoDbObject->set_region('dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com');
```

It might also be that you have two tables in different regions, your application work with one of them and you trying to read (or track with web console) another one because of different default regions applied.

If you're tracking number of items in the table, keep in mind that it is not a real time figure, it is only updated every 6 hours or so. So the way use can ensure your item is indeed written by trying to read it back immediately after you receive the "OK" response for your put request.